# Function parameter style in atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

Is it possible in Atom-editor to configure the styles that would function parameter has right color inside the function? See below

```
function greeting(hello (hello is red color)) {
  // body...
  console.log(hello (hello should be red color, now is it grey) );
}

greeting("HELLO JACK!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My JavaScript parameters show up grey, but regardless this method should work.

1. Open Atom to the JavaScript file you want to change colors in
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Command key if on Mac) to open Developer tools.
3. Click somewhere inside the Dev tools, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to toggle the 'element select' tool.
4. Select the element you would like to change the color of (you're hello inside `console.log()`)
5. Looking at the DOM tree in the dev tools, you can see the classes are `meta arguments js`.
6. Open the `styles.less` file in the root of your Atom directory (where all the application files are)
7. Apply the red color CSS rule to the element of that class:

   `atom-text-editor::shadow .meta.arguments.js {
       color: #e06c75;
   }`
8. You will have to add these two lines to make sure the parentheses stay gray:

   `atom-text-editor::shadow .punctuation.definition.arguments.begin.bracket.round.js {
     color: #abb2bf;
   }`

   `atom-text-editor::shadow .punctuation.definition.arguments.end.bracket.round.js {
     color: #abb2bf;
   }`
9. Then save the file, and your syntax highlighting should update. If not, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to reload the window.
   [image: Style and result]